# Toolbar using drawable at background doesn't display home button within Motorola device

Tags: android, android-layout

When i use a drawable at toolbar background, the home button isn't displayed. Curiously, i just notice that in Motorola device's.

here's the xml layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/topo"
     android:elevation="4dp"
     android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
     app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- the layout which will be the content of the activity (which will be hosted inside the drawer (NOT the list of the drawer)) -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

here's then activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.FontAwesome;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.DrawerBuilder;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.SecondaryDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.SectionDrawerItem;

public class CustomContainerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //save our header or result
    private Drawer result = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_custom_container_dark_toolbar);

        // Handle Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        //Create the drawer
        result = new DrawerBuilder(this)
                //this layout have to contain child layouts
                .withRootView(R.id.drawer_container)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("teste 1").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("teste 1").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_gamepad),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("teste 1").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_eye),
                        new SectionDrawerItem().withName("teste 1"),
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("teste 1").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_cog),
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("teste 1").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_question).setEnabled(false),
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("teste 1").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_github),
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("teste 1").withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_bullhorn)
                )
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //add the values which need to be saved from the drawer to the bundle
        outState = result.saveInstanceState(outState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //handle the back press :D close the drawer first and if the drawer is closed close the activity
        if (result != null && result.isDrawerOpen()) {
            result.closeDrawer();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiDbK.png

Screen  at GenyMotion emulator: Motorola Moto X at left, Samsung S5 at right

The problem occurs in real devices too.

Previewsly, thanks for any help

Comment: try add this sethomebuttonenabled(true). it will wrok .

Comment: that comand is not necessary when using "com.mikepenz.materialdrawer". that's a activity for test, in my real application, that i'm using the layoutDrawer from appCompat, is happening the same problem, and i'm using sethomebuttonenabled(true) and setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

Comment: I solve the problem. i add a imageview with the backgroung transparent, and set a background color to toolbar. Unfortunately, i lose the gradient effect, but i didn't find no other way.